# Is there any restriction for using all APIs in gitlab community edition?

Tags: api, gitlab

I am trying to use api calls for getting the files under a repository and the different commits on a particular repository. I want to know whether all the APIs are available for community edition also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no restriction. Especially the actions you have mentioned are basic features which would be a big drawback if they wouldn't be completely available.

This is the Gitlab API of the community edition: [GitLab CE API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html)

And this is the enterprise edition: [GitLab EE API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html)

For completeness here is the overall comparision of CE and EE: [Compare Gitlab versions](https://about.gitlab.com/comparison/)